# Errors while running examples from boost website

Tags: boost, boost-beast

I installed it from source all according to boost manual with help from several discussions from stackoverflow:
1. apt-get *essentials for boost*
2. ./bootstrap
3. ./b2

Still getting errors, can someone tell from experience on what os examples work. I've tried to install boost for mac but there were linking errors... 1.70 boost is not necessary, maybe previous versions, I just want to try beast in my project (it was introduced in 1.66).

I m trying to build example from beast:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/example/advanced/server/advanced_server.cpp

Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-pthread
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXE=qm

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

terminal:

```
g++ -pthread main.cpp -o main.o
g++  main.o -o qm
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: ZTIv: invalid version 10 (max 0)
main.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'qm' failed
make: *** [qm] Error 1
```

I installed boost from source version 1.7... I've tried to search for this error without any results.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

**Answer:

Just take latest examples from git repos. It helped me, good luck!**